# Edge in IE mode selenium 4 with testNG and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upgrade to selenium 4 to make the tests work in Edge in IE mode. These are Java tests using testNG. The tests work fine when using selenium 3 but fail to launch the browser when using selenium 4. Below is the command used to run the test:

```
$ java -classpath ".\out\production\baseFramework;.\lib\*;.\bin\*" org.testng.TestNG /LoginToHomePage.xml
```

Below is my code to launch the browser:

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);
ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, true);
ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
driver.get(url);
```

I have tried with no options and with a combination of all above options but none of them seem to work. There is no other error displayed other than one below line in stack trace making it difficult to debug.

```
*org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerOptions;)V*
```

Java : 1.8,
testNG : 6.14,
selenium : 4.1.2,
Edge : 99, also tried 97

Works fine from IDE and also works from command line when using selenium 3, but doesn't work from command line if selenium 4 is used. Weirdly, if i expand the command to mention each jar individually under lib, then Edge launches fine but has a problem when i use the wild card lib*. There are more than 80 jars, so running the command with expanded version is not what i prefer. I have tried to turn on debugging in IE driver options but no other logs are printed. I am not sure if its a Java issue or Selenium issue or something else.

All I want to do it to launch Edge browser and cant seem to make it work. Any idea what more I can try would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the description, hope it makes more sense now